# How to use locale message json files of VeeValidate 3 without Node.js, withouf Http Server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localization, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

Locale message files of VeeValidate 2 are javascript,
so I can use like `<script src='./vee-validate/dist/locale/ja.js'>` without Node.js, without Http Server.

but VeeValidate 3, locale message files are just JSON string.
so I can not use like that.

How to use "./vee-validate/dist/locale/ja.json" without Node.js, without Http Server?

(for web designers (not web programmer))

Thanks read my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch` to download the JSON files and merge them in the locale:

```js
await fetch('/vee-validate/dist/locale/ja.json').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
  VeeValidate.localize('ja', data);
});
```